# How to change bootstrap 4 carousel transition duration without modifying bootstrap.js

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

In [bootstrap v3.3.7](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/js/carousel.js), I can change transition duration of carousels by updating css transition time

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out left;
    -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out left;
    -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out left;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out left;
}
```

and overriding bootstrap's Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION variable in my own .js file:

```
$.fn.carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION = 1000;

$('.carousel').carousel();
```

However, in [bootstrap v4](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.0.0-alpha.6/js/src/carousel.js), the carousel.js file was updated, and they extract TRANSITION_DURATION as a constant out of Carousel class. So, the above method does not work any more.

How can I change **transition duration** of carousels in **bootstrap 4 without modifying bootstrap.js**, as all the changes in bootstrap.js would go away when I run a clean build on my project?

Comment: I don't think you can. If you need this behaviour and don't want to modify the source I'd suggest logging a request with them.

Answer (score 0):

Check out how I did it, https://codepen.io/Thumper/pen/JreoPm

The script is watching data-interval="12000" on each .carousel-item div. Change this number to whatever interval you want for each slide.

```
<div class="carousel-item" data-interval="12000">
```

In the script change "#myCarousel" to match the ID or your carousel.

*note, the CSS is only here cause I grabbed the Carousel from their Examples pages.  Also I stole the console.log and placed it in a Bootstrap Alert div to see each slides interval within the page.*

```
var t;
var start = $("#myCarousel")
    .find(".active")
    .data("interval");
t = setTimeout("$('#myCarousel').carousel({interval: 1000});", start - 1000);

$("#myCarousel").on("slid.bs.carousel", function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    var duration = $(this)
        .find("div.carousel-item.active")
        .data("interval");
    console.log(duration);

$("#myCarousel").carousel("pause");
    t = setTimeout("$('#myCarousel').carousel();", duration - 1000);
});

$(".carousel-control-next").on("click", function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
});

$(".carousel-control-prev").on("click", function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
});
```